# NServiceBus 3 persistence in a single RavenDB database

Tags: nservicebus, ravenhq

I have an NServiceBus installation (a single server, obviously).

Is it possible to configure the NSB persistence to use a single RavenDB database (not server)?
If so, what would the configuration be?

The scenario I am thinking about is whether it is possible to use RavenHQ so that all my NSB data is backed up off the machine running the bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the connectionstring option(NServiceBus.Persistence) and point all your endpoints to the same db. Be aware that you need to use NSB 3.2.3 since the TimeoutManager was patched to support this in that version

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I take it that using a single database is a safe approach then and there are no future gremlins waiting for me?

Comment: This is a supported mode of operations so you should be fine